# rails routing devise parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to modify an existing devise route to hold parameters

Here is the working route:

```
  devise_for :contributors, controllers: {registrations: 'contributors/registrations', confirmations: 'contributors/confirmations'}
```

the working path:

```
  <p><a href="<%= new_contributor_registration_path%>" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Create Account</a></p>
```

I need to be able to pass a parameter with it. Is there a simple way to do this?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
  devise_for :contributors, controllers: {registrations: 'contributors/registrations(/:contributor_type)', confirmations: 'contributors/confirmations'}

  <p><a href="<%= new_contributor_registration_path(contributor_type: 'teacher') %>" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Create Account</a></p>
```

but no luck, it only returns this error: wrong constant name Registrations(

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I didn't need to place a parameter inside the devise_for route declaration.

```
  devise_for :contributors, controllers: {registrations: 'contributors/registrations', confirmations: 'contributors/confirmations'}
```

this works just fine with

```
<p><a href="<%= new_contributor_registration_path(contributor_type: 'teacher') %>" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Create Account</a></p>
```